# delete directories recursively on Mac terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I want to delete directories recursively on Mac terminal; directories are named ".picasaoriginals". I tried `rm -r .picasaoriginals` , but it does not do it.

What is the correct command?

Comment: What does the output of the command show?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the command that worked:

```
find . -iname '.picasaoriginals' -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032701/how-to-remove-folders-with-a-certain-name),

```
find . -type d -name .picasaoriginals -exec rmdir {} \;
```

To delete the files within the directories as well, use the `-delete` flag instead of `-exec rmdir {} \;`

Comment: I tried "find . -type d -name .picasaoriginals -delete" but directories ".picasaoriginals" and all files in them are still there. To clarify, I use bash shell on MacOS Big Sur v11.4 and ".picasaoriginals" are "hidden" directories. Obviously, I want to execute it recursively. Any idea?